# How to slice (in Python) "all but the last n" items when n may be zero?

Tags: python, slice

I have a list of items in Python and I need to get "all but the last N" items.  It needs to work when N is zero (in which case I want the whole list) and when N is greater than or equal to the length of the list (in which case I want an empty list).
This works in most cases:

```
mylist=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print( mylist[:-n] )
```

But it fails in the case where N is zero.  `mylist[:0]` returns an empty list: `[]`.  Is there a Python slicing notation that will do what I want, or a simple function?

Comment: You may reverse the list and simply apply the positive slicing notation.

Comment: what if the list is `[1,2,3,4,5]` and n is 6?

Comment: print mylist[:-n] if n>0 else mylist[:]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can pass `None` to the slice

```
print(mylist[:-n or None])
```